# OpenSSL C API: Certificate chain validation with CRL

Tags: c, api, openssl, certificate, authenticode

I'm trying to perform certificate chain validation for Windows executable files, which also includes check for revoked certificates, using OpenSSL 1.0.2 C API.

I have the CRL files stored locally and I want to load them during verification (as opposed to download the CRL via "CRL Distribution Points" URL from certificates which have it).

Here's my simplified example of loading a single CRL file (omitting any error checking):

```
X509_STORE *store = NULL;
X509_STORE_CTX *ctx = NULL;
X509_VERIFY_PARAM *params = NULL;

X509_CRL *crl = d2i_X509_CRL_fp(fc, NULL);  // fc is a file pointer to CRL file
X509_STORE_add_crl(store, crl);
X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, NULL, NULL);

params = X509_STORE_CTX_get0_param(ctx);
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_purpose(params, X509_PURPOSE_ANY);
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags(params, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK);  // only want to check end entity
X509_STORE_set1_param(store, params);

// assume p7 is properly initialized PKCS7*
// assume bio is properly initialized BIO*
int ret = PKCS7_verify(p7, p7->d.sign->cert, store, bio, NULL, 0);
```

Above code will return `ret == 0` with error: `unable to get certificate CRL`, which from my understanding means that OpenSSL is still trying to search CRL from the certificate itself instead of using the one I load locally.

What is the proper way of achieving this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code above is already correct to achieve my goal in performing CRL check.
One potential pitfall for someone new to X509 certificate structure is that ***the "CRL Distribution Points" URL for the certificate of interest is contained within that certificate itself, and not on the issuer's certificate***. This was my mistake which led to the error I mentioned. I hope this may help people who just get started in understanding the X509 standard.